# How to not pull certain files in GitHub?

Tags: git, github

I have a visual studio project that has a folder and runs on each machine, but when I pull it back, it always overwrites the .vs folder. How do I not pull the .vs folder here?

Comment: Consider adding the `.vs` folder to your gitignore file.

Comment: Could you solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can use gitignore file to set a list of files which are to be ignored and left untracked.

https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/saving-changes/gitignore#ignoring-a-previously-committed

> If you want to ignore a file that you've committed in the past, you'll need to delete the file from your repository and then add a .gitignore rule for it. Using the --cached option with git rm means that the file will be deleted from your repository, but will remain in your working directory as an ignored file. For a folder, use -r flag.

```
$ echo .vs >> .gitignore

$ git add .gitignore
  
$ git rm -r --cached .vs
  
$ git commit -m "Start ignoring .vs"
```

Comment: Why you add *default/random* filename (`debug.log`) although the *problem*-folder are specified in the question (`.vs`)? Please add the **exact** *filename/foldername* if mentioned in the question for clarity.

Comment: OK. I will follow it next time. I copied the code from the attached link so thought it's better to paste as-is to avoid confusion with the quoted text.

Answer (score 0):

It's not about which *certain files* are not allowed to be pulled from GitHub, but which *certain files* are written (push) to GitHub. For that reason, write this folder (`.vs`) in your `.gitignore` file.

You can generate simple a default `.gitignore`-file by create a new repository in GitHub and add the filter `VisualStudio`

[image]

Or you can simple add after the repository already created a `.gitignore` file with generated content from [gitignore.io](https://www.toptal.com/developers/gitignore) (same as in GitHub, add `VisualStudio` tag).

[image]

If you already have a `.gitignore` but without the certain folder (`.vs`), just add the folder to the `.gitignore` file

```
.vs
```

---

If the folder `.vs` already pushed to the remote repository (tracked), you must *untrack* git from this folder:

```
git rm -r --cached .vs
```

After this, you must `git add .` and then commit (`git commit -m "No longer tracking .vs to include in gitignore"`) and push (`git push`).